# RISC-V linker relaxation doesn't work for 'tail' pseudoinstruction

Tags: linker, riscv

I use `tail` pseudoinstruction to call an external function, and the function is in the range of `jalr` instruction. But two instructions `auipc` and `jr` are generated from this with GCC version 10.2.1. Won't linker relaxation feature replace these two instructions by `jr` itself? By the way, `call` pseudoinstruction will be replaced by a single `jalr` instruction.

My source code:

```
tail main
```

Generated instructions from disassembly

```
174           tail main    
000000a2:   auipc   t1,0x0
000000a6:   jr      886(t1) # 0x418 <main>
```

Comment: Try to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization. According to ISA manual, `tail` is a pseudoinstruction that convert into `auipc` + `jr`.

Comment: @АлексейХилаев I don't think the post you mentioned is the same question as mine. It explained what's the tail call optimization, not the linker relaxation in RISC-V. From RISC-V ISA manual, yes, `tail` will be converted into `auipc` + `jr`. But I think that's before linker relaxation. Just like `call` will be converted to `auipc` + `jalr` from ISA manual, but actually it will be relaxed to a single `jalr` if the target symbol is in the range of it.